# Using SharePoint resource file in my web part

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, resource-files

I have a SharePoint application and for that I have created resource files which are inside App_GlobalResources folder.

I am making a visual web part and want to use those resource files rather than creating my own. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to use resource file.

In .ascx file:

`<asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:ResourcesFileName, ResourceFileItemKey %>"`

And in .cs file use [SPUtility.GetLocalizedString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx) method

For the second option your resource file should be present in sharepoint mapped resources folder.

For more details visit this [link](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2011/05/24/sharepoint-global-resource-resx-file-locations/)

**Note:** I have trouble using resource file in .ascx file. For more details visit this [link](http://microsofttouch.fr/default/b/vincent/archive/2013/04/07/english-the-name-39-initializecontrol-39-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-controles-utilisateur-sharepoint-2013-and-ressources.aspx)